# How to display "No data available" in datatable after deleting rows

Tags: datatables

I have datatable with action onclick delete function that deleting the row.
How can i display "no data available" in case i delete all the row?

Here's my code.

```
        {
            "data": "Action",
            render: (data, type, row) => {
                return `<div class="actionIcon"><a id="viewExamination" onclick="individualDetails('${row["NAME"]}', '${row["BIRTHDAY"]}', '${row["Phone Number"]}')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#asdffdsddd" data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false"><i class="fa-solid fa-outdent"></i></a><a id="delThisData" onclick="deleteDetailsNewHired()"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> </a> </div>`;
            }
        }

   function deleteDetailsNewHired() {
       $("#delThisData").closest('tr').remove();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the data stored inside the DataTables object and the data you can see displayed in the web page. If you only delete a `<tr>` from the HTML, you have not deleted that row from the underlying DataTable.

See the DataTables API function [`row().remove()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()).

Note the use of the `draw()` function as well, to re-draw the table data so you actually see the resuts of the `remove()` operation reflected in the HTML.

After that, you can take a look at the [`language.emptyTable`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable) option (which you set once as part of the table definition) if you want to use a custom message. By default, the message you see is:

```
No data available in table
```

But it can be anything you want.

---

This is a similar overall issue as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74805943/how-can-i-access-all-table-row-in-datatable#comment132020724_74805943). It is important to understand the difference between the data stored in your DataTable and the data which happens to be rendered on the currently visible web page.