# How can i access all table row in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to select all the table row, but i can only access all rows which shown in the current page of the DataTable

(I'm using table row class attr to access).

Is there any way to access all row in all pages in DataTable?

Here's what i tried and it can only select all rows in current page

```
   $("#uploadAllDataNewHired").click(function () {
      var tableRow = $(".rowArray");
   })
```

Comment: Use the DataTables API. The data in the DOM (the visible HTML table elements) is typically not the same as (i.e. only a subset of) the data in the underlying DataTables JavaScript object. There are various approaches - one being: `var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();` and then `table.rows().data();`. See [`rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()).

Comment: See also [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+get+all+data+site:stackoverflow.com) with various answers and solutions. I think this is something which should be easy for you to research further for yourself.